# Как отключить кеширование определенного url?

Tags: ajax, opencart

Делаю магазин на Opencart 3.0.2.0 и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Когда добавляю товар в корзину информация в мини корзине не обновляется. В demo версии Opencart все отлично работает. Так же все отлично работает с включенным Disable cache в панели разработчика.
[image: Видно разницу реально добавленных товаров от отображаемых]

[image: С отключенным cache все отлично работает]
[image: С отключенным cache все отлично работает]

Вот JS код который отвечает за добавление, обновление и удаление товаров из корзины

```
var cart = {
'add': function(product_id, quantity) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        cache:false,
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#cart > .mini-cart_hook').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#cart > .mini-cart_hook').button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            $('.alert-dismissible, .text-danger').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

                // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#cart > .mini-cart_hook').html('<i class="fal fa-shopping-cart"></i><span id="cart-total">' + json['total'] + '</span>');
                }, 100);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
},
'update': function(key, quantity) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/edit',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'key=' + key + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#cart > .mini-cart_hook').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#cart > .mini-cart_hook').button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#cart > .mini-cart_hook').html('<i class="fal fa-shopping-cart"></i><span id="cart-total">' + json['total'] + '</span>');
            }, 100);

            if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
                location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
            } else {
                $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
},
'remove': function(key) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/remove',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'key=' + key,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#cart > .mini-cart_hook').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#cart > .mini-cart_hook').button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#cart > .mini-cart_hook').html('<i class="fal fa-shopping-cart"></i><span id="cart-total">' + json['total'] + '</span>');
            }, 100);

            if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
                location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
            } else {
                $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

}

А вот сам непосредственный кусок кода который должен обновлять информацию, но браузер подтягивает ee из cache

```
$('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
```

Подскажите как с этим бороться. Как отключить кеширование для определенного URL и получать обновленные данные из базы а не из from disk cache?

Извиняюсь за сумбурность!

Comment: Инвалидация кеша - самая сложная задача в программировании)